# ionic issue on different version

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created two codepen

one is using with **0.9.27** and other with **1.0.0-rc.4**

for **0.9.27**

```
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/JdtuG

And for **1.0.0-rc.4***

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJgmyx

Now problem is that **0.9.27** is working fine but  **1.0.0-rc.4** is not

Screen Shot for Error [image]

and working Screen shot !
[image]
Image link
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlCM5.png
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Which one is not working here ??

Comment: 1.0.0-rc.4 is not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: you can visit both codepen link.

Comment: I don't get any differences between two.

Comment: i have added screen shots for both

Comment: working one has a class has-header added to it (in the dom) which has a top style of 44px, but the second one has a directive has-header set to true, but no class being appended to it in the dom.

Comment: Could you provide example for the same. i remvoed has-header but still not working